# Extract multiple datapoints from a child array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I've been building a small project and reached a bit of a brick wall.
I have an array that contains two arrays, as seen in the code snippet. I'm using this to build a little HTML table of results.

The problem is that in my second column, it is printing out only the *last* element from the child arrays (the cat_type). What *should* be printed are all three bits of that child array, so the cell on row one should read "1 Yellow Lion" and on row two "2 Orange Tiger".

I am versed in JS enough to know my problem is the line that says `newCell.textContent = value;`. The element 'value' is cycling through all three bits of the child array and ending at the cat_type so it is set to that when it comes to print.
What I am experienced enough in is knowing *how* to grab all three bits of data. Do I need to include another **for** loop in there to iterate through that array? It seems bad form to nest so many for loops inside one another.

Edit: I know the code snippet is throwing an error and looks messy; that's fine and isn't part of the problem. It is just the specific question about how to get the three pieces of information printing into the cell I'm concerned about.

```js
var MyArray = ['Cats', [{
  cat_num: '1',
  cat_colour: 'Yellow',
  cat_type: 'Lion'
}, {
  cat_num: '2',
  cat_colour: 'Orange',
  cat_type: 'Tiger'
}]];

catsTbl = document.getElementById("catsTable");

var catsArray = Object.entries(MyArray);
arrMax = Math.max(...catsArray.map(el => el[1].length));

const headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
catsTbl.appendChild(headerRow);

for (let x = 0; x < arrMax; x++) {
  const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
  catsTbl.appendChild(newRow);
}

for (let i = 0; i < catsArray.length; i++) {
  const newCell = document.createElement("th");
  newCell.textContent = catsArray[0];
  headerRow.appendChild(newCell);
  for (let x = 0; x < arrMax; x++) {
    const newCell = document.createElement("td");
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(catsArray[i][1][x])) {
      newCell.textContent = value;
      catsTbl.children[x + 1].appendChild(newCell);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id='catsTable' border=1></table>
```

Comment: Why is `MyArray` an array? Arrays should be used for uniform data, but `MyArray` contains a string an an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to the way you're iterating through the nested arrays and populating the table cells. You're overwriting the cell content in the inner loop, so only the last value is being displayed in each cell. To display all three values from each child array in the second column, you need to create a new cell for each value and append them to the row:

```js
var MyArray = ['Cats', [{cat_num: '1', cat_colour: 'Yellow', cat_type: 'Lion'},{cat_num: '2', cat_colour: 'Orange', cat_type: 'Tiger'}]];

catsTbl = document.getElementById("catsTable");

var catsArray = Object.entries(MyArray);
arrMax = Math.max(...catsArray.map(el => el[1].length));

const headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
catsTbl.appendChild(headerRow);

// Create header cells
for (let i = 0; i < catsArray.length; i++) {
    const newCell = document.createElement("th");
    newCell.textContent = catsArray[i][0];
    headerRow.appendChild(newCell);
}

// Create data cells
for (let x = 0; x < arrMax; x++) {
    const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    catsTbl.appendChild(newRow);

    for (let i = 0; i < catsArray.length; i++) {
        const newCell = document.createElement("td");
        if (catsArray[i][1][x]) {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(catsArray[i][1][x])) {
                newCell.textContent += value + ' ';
            }
        }
        newRow.appendChild(newCell);
    }
}
```

```html
<table id='catsTable' border=1></table>
```